# How to slice a JPEG into HTML

Tags: html, css, web, slice

I have a JPEG image that I want to slice into HTML, I am little confused about positioning things into divs. Can anyone suggest me how can I do this I am sending the jpeg along with the question.
[image]

Regards
Umair

Comment: what do you want to achieve, that is not clear from your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would look at what pieces seem to contain themselves. For instance, the fill out the form box would be a div, the legal info at the bottom would be a div, the why use online box would be a div, the 2 header pieces would also be a div. You could wrap the entire thing in a div and use a css sprite image ([CSS Sprite article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites)) for the background gradient.`enter code here`

```
<div id=pageWrapper>
   <div id=header1>OnlineGrantFinders.com</div>
   <div id=header2>Looking for grant money?</div>
   <div id=mainContent>
      <div class='infoText'>You can apply for grants ....</div>
      <div class='infoText' id='whyUseUs'>Why Use Online Grant Finders.com....</div>
      <div id=fileForm>Fill Out the form below....</div>
   </div>
   <div id='footer'>This website is owned...</div>
</div>
```

The css shouldn't be too difficult from here. If you don't know about floating elements I would look into that and learn how to clear them as well. The fileForm element would be best as an absolutely positioned element I would suspect.

Comment: you know the problem is that if I make things absolutely position I fear that they would be misplaced on changing the resolution.

Comment: you could also position relative and use %margins to get the top and right. It would still take up space in the wrapper class but would move with the page (on second thought %margins with position absolute might work as well).